# MySQL GROUP BY acting strange, not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to return the row with **ID 258776**, here's what I've tried so far...

Here's my example, I use the `AND msg.uid` to only get one thread of messages. I want to return the latest post of each thread therefore in the example with just 2 messages for 1 thread, I want the row with **ID 258776** to be returned.

Without GROUP BY:

```
SELECT main.id, main.message_id, main.inbox_id, main.uid, main.body, main.created_at FROM (
                SELECT i.id as inbox_id, i.message_id, msg.* FROM inbox AS i
                INNER JOIN message AS msg ON i.message_id = msg.id
                WHERE i.profile_id = 2135
                AND i.is_sent = 0
                AND i.is_deleted = 0
                #AND msg.uid = '570cc3a568402'
                ORDER BY msg.updated_at DESC
            ) AS main #GROUP BY main.uid


= ID =  =MSG =  =INB =  = UID       =   = BD =   = CREATED         =  
258776  258776  524785  570cc3a568402   wtf      2016-06-22 11:34:29  
217149  217149  438907  570cc3a568402   <br />   2016-04-12 11:45:09
```

Try with GROUP BY

```
SELECT main.id, main.message_id, main.inbox_id, main.uid, main.body, main.created_at FROM (
                SELECT i.id as inbox_id, i.message_id, msg.* FROM inbox AS i
                INNER JOIN message AS msg ON i.message_id = msg.id
                WHERE i.profile_id = 2135
                AND i.is_sent = 0
                AND i.is_deleted = 0
                #AND msg.uid = '570cc3a568402'
                ORDER BY msg.updated_at DESC
            ) AS main GROUP BY main.uid

= ID =  =MSG =  =INB =  = UID       =   = BD =   = CREATED         =  
217149  217149  438907  570cc3a568402   <br />   2016-04-12 11:45:09
```

Switch to ASC but GROUP BY gives same results ?

```
SELECT main.id, main.message_id, main.inbox_id, main.uid, main.body, main.created_at FROM (
                SELECT i.id as inbox_id, i.message_id, msg.* FROM inbox AS i
                INNER JOIN message AS msg ON i.message_id = msg.id
                WHERE i.profile_id = 2135
                AND i.is_sent = 0
                AND i.is_deleted = 0
                #AND msg.uid = '570cc3a568402'
                ORDER BY msg.updated_at ASC
            ) AS main GROUP BY main.uid

= ID =  =MSG =  =INB =  = UID       =   = BD =   = CREATED         =  
217149  217149  438907  570cc3a568402   <br />   2016-04-12 11:45:09
```

I presume it should work fine if I didn't need to use an INNER join ? :(

**EDIT:**

Here's some more data from the `message` table and `inbox` table.

`message`

```
= ID =  =FROMID=  = UID       = = TITLE = = BODY =  = CREATED         =
258776  52169     570cc3a568402 RE: RE:   wtf       2016-06-22 11:34:29  
258775  2135      570cc3a568402 RE: You   Testtest  2016-06-22 11:31:29 
258774  34833     576a590fdf9e5 RE: Sure  < 3 < 3   2016-06-22 11:24:08  
258773  34833     576a590fdf9e5 RE: Sure  sok       2016-06-22 11:23:57     
258772  34833     576a590fdf9e5 RE: Sure  hey hey   2016-06-22 11:23:46
```

`inbox`

```
= ID =  = PROFILE =   = MSG_ID =   = IS_SENT = = IS_READ = = IS_DELETED =
524785  2135          258776       0           0           0
524784  52169         258776       1           1           0
524783  52169         258775       0           1           0
524782  2135          258775       1           0           0
524781  2135          258774       0           1           0
```

Comment: Why are you using group by? And why are you using a subquery?

Comment: `Group by` used without aggregation (aggregate functions like sum count avg etc) will behave similar to a `distinct`, at times. It can also be used for special grouping strategies for finding the first row of an inner grouping. Until you become a pro at sql, be wary of fringe uses of it.

Comment: The source of non-aggregated fields not included in the group by is not guaranteed by MySQL (other than they will come from some pre-grouping result that matches on the grouped fields) so I'd argue even pros should stay away from such uses.

Comment: Updated with sample of the two tables :/

Comment: if you can provide a proper sqlfiddle (schema and data load), then one of us can figure this out. It is hard to make heads or tails of it

Comment: The best one can do is hack a table together from what you have shown. It takes like 10 minutes then you are missing columns. So, you need to save people the grief of like the last 10 minutes I spent just trying to get test data put together just to find out you are missing date columns. Like `main.created_at` which is not in your derived table and therefore your output did not come from that query

Comment: `CREATED = created_at`... Anyway I went with using PDO to get full list then PHP to loop through and build-up array of IDs but set key to be uid so it overwrites if it found messages that are newer for that `uid` (thread)... then added a `->andWhereIn` clause which worked fine.

Comment: next time, sqlfiddle is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PHP to solve my problem, by performing a PDO query to select all the messages, then loop through these results to have a simple array of message IDs grouped by the thread ID (uid)...

```
$pdo = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
$results = $pdo->execute('SELECT i.id, i.message_id, msg.uid FROM inbox AS i
            INNER JOIN message AS msg ON i.message_id = msg.id
            WHERE i.profile_id = :profile_id
            AND i.is_sent = :is_sent
            AND i.is_deleted = :is_deleted
            ORDER BY msg.created_at ASC', [
        ':profile_id' => $address->getId(),
        ':is_sent' => 0,
        ':is_deleted' => 0,
    ])->fetchAll();

$whereIn = [];

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    $whereIn[$value['uid']] = $value['id'];
}

return $this
        ->getBaseMessageBoxQuery()
        ->addWhere('i.profile_id = ?', $address->getId())
        ->andWhere('i.is_sent = 0')
        ->andWhere('i.is_deleted = 0')
        ->andWhereIn('i.id', array_values($whereIn))
        ->addGroupBy('msg.uid')
        ->orderBy('msg.created_at DESC');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the max id that match you condition you should use

```
SELECT main.id, main.message_id, main.inbox_id, main.uid, main.body, main.created_at 
    FROM (
            SELECT i.id as inbox_id, i.message_id, msg.* FROM inbox AS i
            INNER JOIN message AS msg ON i.message_id = msg.id
            WHERE i.id = (    

                SELECT max(i.id)  FROM inbox AS i
                INNER JOIN message AS msg ON i.message_id = msg.id
                WHERE i.profile_id = 2135
                AND i.is_sent = 0
                AND i.is_deleted = 0
                AND msg.uid = '570cc3a568402'

            )


        ) AS main
```

Group by like said in comment are for aggegatte function (with multiplr result)  you don't have this then you don't need

Comment: I can't use max(i.id) since I need to get the latest of each thread... I will add more data from each table... :/ It's a terrible DB structure someone else made :(

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate my original comment; unless there is some unusual logic you are trying to implement, I really don't see a need for either the `GROUP BY` or the subquery; just use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT msg.id, i.message_id, i.id as inbox_id, msg.uid, msg.body, msg.created_at
FROM inbox AS i
INNER JOIN message AS msg ON i.message_id = msg.id
WHERE i.profile_id = 2135
   AND i.is_sent = 0
   AND i.is_deleted = 0
   AND msg.uid = '570cc3a568402'
ORDER BY msg.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

EDIT: With the additional information, this should allow you to get what you want with just a query:

```
SELECT m.id, i.message_id, i.id as inbox_id, m.uid, m.body, m.created_at
FROM 
(SELECT uid, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at
FROM message
GROUP BY uid) AS lastMs
INNER JOIN message AS m USING(uid, updated_at)
INNER JOIN inbox AS i ON m.id = i.message_id
```

The primary concern I can see with this query, or any possible solution, with the problem as it has been described so far is that it is possible there may be multiple messages with the same `uid` AND `updated_at`; in which case, multiple results would be returned for that `uid`.

Comment: I cannot use LIMIT 1 because I need to get the 'latest message' for all threads... I just added the AND msg.uid to show 1 thread, sorry I should have made this clear in the post :) will update

Comment: @dan2k3k4 See addition to my answer.